# How to make a duplicate parellel copy of an Infopath 2010 form to test

Tags: infopath

Is there a way to copy a duplicate copy of a infopath form place it in a parallel or different folder, modify and test it?

I don't mind that it writes to the same database but it's the original form that I want to make sure is secured along with the SharePoint workflow.

Comment: so you want to make replica of your info-path form on new site collection

Comment: same site collection - just a copy that I can modify and test live without affecting the original.  They seriously do not have a DEV area.

Comment: so you are using form library right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Open Form Library using SharePoint Designer
2. Export **template.xsn** file on local machine
3. Open that template.xsn file from Info-path form designer
4. Replace all data connection.
5. Publish to server.
6. create new library while publishing

Comment: Welcome you are!